FFMPEG, имеет ли значение расширение входного файла?
Есть видео, хотел бы убрать у файла расширение.
FFMPEG модуль, смотрит ли на то какого расширение видео(входной файл) или все равно. Главное входной файл был и было это видео?

кажется быстрее было бы проверить самому.

FFmpeg supports the following file formats through the libavformat library

Кажется он может выбирать кодеки основываясь на расширении, но всегда можно задать явно параметром

То есть, если кодек не указан. Будет смотреть на расширение входного файла. Если же к примеру в команде прописан параметр -c:v libvpx-vp9 тогда уже все равно что за расширение у файла

Судя по всему так, но можешь просто попробовать
